# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoplot'

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b1e30ae19d82> in <module>
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 import geopandas as gpd
----> 6 import geoplot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoplot'
```

Comment: I really don't see the point of this question, what does this add which can't already be found on Stack Overflow or the Conda docs?

Answer (score 1):

The default Anaconda Cloud channels do not host `geoplot`, but it can be found on the Conda Forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geoplot
```